# ListView displaying object's details

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

What I am trying to achieve in my Android app is to have a `ListView` which is displaying fields from objects. Lets say I have an object called Person with properties like Name, Address, Age and so on. I want to have each property from Person as one item in a `ListView` (Name would be in first row, address would be in  second row...).

How can I do that if I am not using array as a source of `ListView` but properties from object? Everywhere I can find tutorials with ArrayList and ArrayAdapter but this I can't use. Thanks.

Comment: @"but properties from object" and how are you keeping track of the objects? Please post your code as well. It would be easier to know where you're stuck

Comment: Why do you want to use ListView for this purpose? ListView is used to display list of identical items. Do you want to show a list of Person?

Comment: I have a list of Persons which is displayed in the first ListView and when user select a person, next ListView which details is displayed. I want to use ListView because Person has many fields and I would like to display them as a list

Answer (score 0):

Listview needs data to display. Data is provided by Adapter. Adapter needs source of data. Be it ArrayList or database. So either basically you may need to your objects in ArrayList and then you can access object properties for each row displayed.

Answer (score 0):

For this one you need to create a adapter and a single view to load for list,

for example,
create a layout resource file like this,

//layout/single_rsr_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/list_item_back">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/img_sin_list_image"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.2">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeTextandroid:elliklm;ml;;m;psize="
                    android:id="@+id/tv_single_list_rsr_description"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
                    android:maxEms="11"
                    android:lines="2"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="2015/03/13 1:10"
                    android:id="@+id/tv_sin_list_rsr_date"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_single_list_rsr_description"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/ring_color" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="Small Text"
                    android:id="@+id/tv_sin_list_rsr_id"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_sin_list_rsr_date"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_sin_list_rsr_date"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tv_sin_list_rsr_date" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

now create a claas to get what you need like this,

```
public class RSRData {
    private int id;
    private String description;
    private String date;
    private String imagePath;

    public RSRData() {
    }

    public RSRData(int id, String imagePath, String description, String date) {
        this.id = id;
        this.imagePath = imagePath;
        this.description = description;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getImagePath() {
        return imagePath;
    }

    public void setImagePath(String imagePath) {
        this.imagePath = imagePath;
    }
}
```

then wite a adapter like this with converst this to a repeating list like this,

```
public class RSRAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RSRData> {

    Context con;
    int res;

    public RSRAdapter(Context context,int resource,ArrayList<RSRData> rsrData){
        super(context,resource,rsrData);
        this.con = context;
        this.res = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        RSRData rsrData=getItem(position);

        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflator=LayoutInflater.from(con);
            convertView=inflator.inflate(res,parent,false);
        }

        TextView tvTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_single_list_rsr_description);
        tvTitle.setText(rsrData.getDescription());

        TextView tvId = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_sin_list_rsr_id);
        tvId.setText(rsrData.getId());

        TextView date = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_sin_list_rsr_date);
        date.setText(rsrData.getDate());

      /*  ImageVi = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_primaryKey);
        tvPrimaryKey.setText(String.valueOf(promotionData.getId()));*/


        return convertView;
    }
}
```

after all done, use this to set data to your list view,

```
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.your_list);
ArrayList<RSRAdapter> data = new ArrayList<>(); // use this to get data from database and pass to here,

RSRAdapter adapter = new RSRAdapter(this,R.layout.sigle_promotion_item,data);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
```